# Tess4J working as standalone in 64 bit windows, But fails in Tomcat 7

Tags: windows, eclipse, tomcat7, ocr

Trying OCR with Tess4J and able to make it work as a standalone application on 64 bit windows.
I am using eclipse for the same.
Now I am trying to create a war of the same code and deploy it in Tomcat7 and call the api using a servlet. I am getting following error.

```
     java.util.NoSuchElementException
javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(ServiceRegistry.java:808)
javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:816)
javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:801)
net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getImageByteBuffer(ImageIOHelper.java:190)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:133)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:88)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:75)
com.hp.cto.TextReading.doGet(TextReading.java:35)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solutions are given in [How to resolve OutOfMemoryError with ImageIO plugins as the cause](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17365294/267197) and in [comment #13 for bug 788160 (Error reading in TIFF images)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/goobi-production/+bug/788160/comments/13).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have `jai_imageio` in your `CLASSPATH` or in your `WEB-INF/lib`. 
Call `ImageIO.scanForPlugins();` before you call `doOCR`.