# My Java SPI extension is not loaded

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Background: In my project, I have to fetch images from the web and resize them before storage. To do so, I use imgscalr to resize the pictures, which uses the ImageIO API of Java.

The thing is that the ImageIO API does not seem to support CMYK color space for JPEG, thus it fails to read some pictures fetched from our data provider (I can't change the picture format).

To add support for CMYK, I've found a nice lib (which I'm trying to package as a maven artifact and enhance a bit) that is an ImageReaderSpi extension.

So far, so good. The problem I'm facing is that the extension does not seem to be loaded by the ImageIO API, it acts as if it wasn't present.

I've created a maven artifact which is a simple jar containing the extension implementation and the `META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi` file containing the name of the class that implements the Spi.

I'm sure that the jar is in the classpath because I'm using a helper in it and it is found.

For the record, I'm deploying the project (a WAR) into Tomcat, and the extension jar is in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

The jar source code is [available here](https://github.com/BluePyth/jpeg-cmyk) the META-INF file is included during the maven build (the @MetaInfServices annotation does that).

I'm stuck here, I think I'm doing things right, that's why I'm looking for your help!

Comment: This could be a class loader issue.  Your SPI may be being loaded in a class loader that exists higher then the system class loader and therefore is not accessible to it (you can only look down the hierarchy, not up).  Have you tried adding the Jar containing your SPI to the `ext` folder of the JRE that Tomcat is using?

Comment: And is the service file actually there when you deploy with the good entries etc? Are you sure that, for instance, it is not overwritten by another step of the build process somewhere?

Comment: MadProgrammer: I've tried it, but maybe I didn't try in the right JVM, will retry.

Comment: fge: the file is there, that is for sure.

Comment: Have you tried writing a small, standalone Java program to verify that your JAR/plugin works and loads as it should (without the web app related problems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some potential pitfalls with using ImageIO plugins loaded from WEB-INF/lib, due to the `ClassLoader` hierarchy in a web container (as mentioned by @MadProgrammer in the comments section). Adding the plugins to the web containers shared libs folder (or classpath) is usually the best and easiest way.

If you for some reason you need to have the plugins bundled within your app, you need to call `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` from somewhere in the web app.

This will make the plugins available, but introduces a resource/memory leak (the plugins stay in memory after web app redeploy).

See my answer in the thread [How to resolve OutOfMemoryError with ImageIO plugins as the cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357969/how-to-resolve-outofmemoryerror-with-imageio-plugins-as-the-cause/17365294#17365294) for analysis and solution to both problems.

Comment: I've also tried to put the jar in the lib folder, but will retry + add the ImageIO.scanForPlugins() call.

Comment: Thanks Harald, it seems that the problem was indeed ClassLoader related. I've used your solution. I've also published my library at http://bluepyth.github.io/jpeg-cmyk/ it includes your ContextListener. Thanks for it :)

Comment: I 'just' used the ContextListener. The rest of the code was taken from another person :)